# Error conexión mariadb + wordpress con docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tengo un docker-compose donde levanto dos contenedores uno con `mariadb` y otro con `wordpress`.

---

**El problema:**

Recibo un fallo de conexión, la parecer pierde el user y no puede realizar la authentication.

> wp-mysql | 2019-08-09 13:21:16 18 [Warning] Aborted connection 18 to
>   db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.31.0.3' (This
>   connection closed normally without authentication)

Otra alerta que salta en los logs ...

> WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db:3306' wp-web
>   |   continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)

---

**Situación**

Cuando entro al `http://localhost:8010` el servicio de wordpress está disponible, pero con error de conexión a la BBDD.

El **docker-compose.yml** ...

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: wp-mysql
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
       - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    ports:
       - "3307:3306"
    networks:
       - my_net
    restart: on-failure

  wp:
    depends_on:
       - db
    container_name: wp-web
    volumes:
       - "$PWD/html:/var/www/html"
    image: wordpress
    ports:
       - "8010:80"
    environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
       - my_net

networks:
  my_net:
```

---

El `docker ps`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

¿Dónde está el error de configuración?

¿Por qué no puede el contendor de wordpress no puede utilizar el `user` creado en el `environment` del contenedor de mariadb?

---

**EDITO**

Esta versión ***tampoco*** me funciona...

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: wp-mysql
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
       - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    ports:
       - "3307:3306"
    expose:
      - "3307"
    networks:
       - my_net
    restart: on-failure

  wp:
    depends_on:
       - db
    container_name: wp-web
    volumes:
       - "$PWD/html:/var/www/html"
    image: wordpress
    ports:
       - "8010:80"
    environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db:3306"
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "wordpress"
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "wordpress"
    networks:
       - my_net

networks:
  my_net:
```

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias por el aporte. pero ese no es el problema. Ya tenía buena conexión, solamente es la autentificación. Igualmente lo he probado. Pero entonces el error es de conectividad.  Witch 3307: `WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db:3307'
wp-web |   continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)
`

Comment: Puse las comillas y nada. Expuse el puerto en el ado de mysql el 3307, en el lado del wp el 3306 y nada, he probado varias combinaciones y no parecer ser ese el problema. Otro error que veo es... `WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db:3306'
wp-web |   continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)
`

Comment: Con el puerto 3307 expuesto y cambiado el wp-mysql, obtengo el mismo error: `WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'wp-mysql:3306'
wp-web |   continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)
`

Comment: Nada no funciono.

Comment: He probado otro docker-compose [https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/] y me pasa lo mismo. Así que debe ser algo de mi configuración local. Trabajo con Debian 9 y mariadb pero no se si tendra que ver algo. A ver si alguien puede aportar algo de luz, ya que parece ser que los docker-compose están correctos pero algo falla en mi configuración local??? :(

Comment: lo unico que puede fallar es el archivo compartido, es decir el volumen no pudo ser compartido, por curiosidad como root te conecta, el contenedor db arroja algun error?

Comment: He cambiado los directorios `data` y `html` a 777 y nada sigue igual. La verdad es que soy un poco novato con docker e igual hay alguna cosa elemental que se me está escapando.

Comment: pero hagamos algo, coloquemos solo en el docker-compose la imagen de mariadb  y probemos; luego te intentas conectar con gestor de base de datos a ver si no tienes problemas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97247/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-eduard-pinuaga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo solucione.

Después de estar dando muchas vueltas y ayudado por el usuario @JackNavaRow salio la solución.

Fue tan sencillo como reiniciar el sistema y borrar los volúmenes.

Levante los contendores y todo funciono ok.

Lo dejo aquí por si alguien se encuentra con este problemon, que no le dé más vueltas.

---

**EDITADO**

***Otro posible error*** es poner dentro de `en la parte de` el nombre de la base de datos sino utilizara el nombre por defecto.

Tendría que poner ...

```
WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

En este ejemplo el nombre es el por defecto pero si hubiéramos puesto  otro nombre en `MYSQL_DATABASE: otro_nombre` En caso de no especificar en el `wp-config` saldría como base de datos `wordpress` (por defecto)

Comment: por cierto , con este caso queda demostrado a nivel informatico *"nunca dudes el poder de un reinicio de sistema operativo"*